# Transfer of files from unsecured hdfs to secured hdfs cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, kerberos, distcp

I wanted to transfer files from unsecured HDFS cluster to kerberized cluster. I am using distcp to transfer the files. I have used the following command.

```
hadoop distcp -D ipc.client.fallback-to-simple-auth-allowed=true hdfs://<ip>:8020/<sourcedir> hdfs://<ip>:8020/<destinationdir>
```

I am getting the following error after I executed the above command in the kerberized cluster.

```
java.io.EOFException: End of File Exception between local host is: "<xxx>"; destination host is: "<yyy>; : java.io.EOFException; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EOFException
```

Comment: can you try using `webhdfs:/` instead of `hdfs:/`?

Comment: for both clusters uris'?

Comment: Tried with webhdfs. But getting below exception '17/02/15 11:42:17 ERROR tools.DistCp: Invalid arguments: java.io.IOException: Unexpected HTTP response: code=404 != 200, op=GETDELEGATIONTOKEN, message=Not Found'

Comment: try `webhdfs` instead of hdfs for the nonsecure host and `hdfs` for sercure

Comment: tried that too. same error

Comment: can you check if port 8020 is open on secured cluster?

Comment: ohh for webhdfs you should use for 50070 `webhdfs://yyy:50070/target_path`

Comment: oh k. thanks. it worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135800/discussion-between-midhun-mathew-sunny-and-ronak-patel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is error because:

> cluster is blocked for RPC communication, in such cases, webhdfs
>   protocol can be used, so above distcp can be rewritten as

```
hadoop distcp -D ipc.client.fallback-to-simple-auth-allowed=true hdfs://xxx:8020/src_path webhdfs://yyy:50070/target_path
```

this is very good [blog post for distcp](http://www.beingsoftwareprofessional.com/2016/05/11/copying-data-between-hadoop-environments-distcp/)